# Validation check of object?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am having problem that it is not throwing an error if the `payload` does not Prop1 OR Prop2

What went wrong?

```js
const payload = {
    Prop3: {
      Field1: 1,
      Field2: 2,
    }
}

if ((!payload.Prop1 && typeof payload.Prop1 === "object") || (!payload.Prop2 && typeof payload.Prop2 === "object")) {
    throw new Error("Must contain Prop1 or Prop2")
}
```

Comment: `typeof payload.Prop1` is `undefined` (same for `Prop2`) so both conditions evaluate to `false`. Did you intend to have `!== 'object'`?

Comment: Neither condition will pass? Since there is no `Prop1` - it never evaluates `typeof payload.Prop1 === "object"`

Answer (score 0):

That is because `typeof undefined` is `undefined` and not object.

Here Prop1 is undefined and its typeof is not "object" 
So, your code never satisfies if condition

You could write

```
(!payload.Prop1 && typeof payload.Prop1 !== "object") || (!payload.Prop2 && typeof payload.Prop2 !== "object")
```

if you are expecting Prop1 and Prop2 to be objects

Answer (score 0):

```
(!payload.Prop1 && typeof payload.Prop1 === "object")
```

returns true if `payload` does not have `Prop1` AND `Prop1` is of type `object` which is not what you want. It should be

```
(!payload.Prop1 && typeof payload.Prop1 !== "object")
```